# Lapply for dlply

Tags: r, plyr, lm

I'm trying to apply a linear regression to a list of data frames, filtered for a specific value.
For example, having a list of Iris data frames, I'm trying to run a regression for `Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width`, with each species running a different regression.

```r
test <- dlply(iris, "Species", function(x) lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = x))
```

but i want to do it for a list of dataframes at the same time, rather than individually. So, say i had a list of multiple iris data frames:

```
 iris1 <- iris
 iris2 <- iris
 iris3 <- iris
iris_list <- list(iris1, iris2, iris3)
```

So, to run the dlply code to `iris_list`, I'm lost.

Comment: Why not try `lapply`?

Comment: I tried but couldnt get it running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `lapply`,

```
res = lapply(iris_list, function(x){
  test <- dlply(x, "Species", function(x) lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = x))
  return(test)
})
```

Comment: This seemed to work. Thanks!
I was trying to do it with lapply but clearly doign it the wrong way;
lapply(data_list,dlply(data_list, "UF", function(x) lm(VD4020~V2007, data = x) )

Answer (score 0):

**purrr**

Try using `purrr::map` if you want to apply a regression across a list of data frames:

```
library(purrr)

map(iris_list, ~ lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = .x))
```

If you want to split a data frame into a list based on a factor you can use `split` from base R first:

```
imap(split(iris, ~ Species), ~ lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = .x))
```

Note: `imap` is used in this case to preserve the list names, which are the levels of `Species` in this case.

**base R**

If you only want to use base R and `lapply` then this will work:

```
lapply(split(iris, ~ Species), function(x) lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = x))
```

---

If you have a nested list then you need to nest your mapping:

```
library(purrr)

map(iris_list, ~ imap(split(.x, ~ Species), ~ lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = .x)))
```

And again in base R:

```
lapply(iris_list, function(x) lapply(split(x, ~ Species), function(y) lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = y)))
```

Comment: But then i run into the same problem of having to run that command to all the data frames in the list manually.

Comment: @Lelleo can you try clarifying more? `map`, `imap`, and `lapply` *iterate* over list elements so you do not have to run that command multiple times.